# API Manager 1.8 cannot join ELB cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have tried some attempts to install API Manager 1.8 in ELB cluster environment, but never succeed (ELB log didn't display the message for joining cluster, just display "No application members available" when access API Manager).

Instead of that, I used API Manager 1.7 could be successful.

Any issues with that?

Configuration in loadbalancer.conf of ELB 2.1.1 (IP:192.168.111.12):

```
apimanager {
  domains{
    abc.wso2api.domain {
        tenant_range    *;
        group_mgt_port 4570;
        mgt {
            hosts   mgt.wso2api.abc.com;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Configuration in axis2.xml of API Manager 1.8 (IP:192.168.111.155):

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
            enable="true">
...
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
...
<parameter name="domain">abc.wso2api.domain</parameter>
...
<parameter name="localMemberHost">192.168.111.155</parameter>
...
<members>
  <member>
    <hostName>192.168.111.12</hostName>
    <port>4570</port>
  </member>
</members>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen due to Hazelcast version miss match. Check Hazelcast versions of each product. You are better off with **nginx**